# How can I send files or cookies through a socket? Using FastCGI with Rust

Tags: php, cookies, rust, fastcgi

I am currently trying to implement the [FastCGI protocol](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119141816/http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/6?q=node%2F22#S1) in rust to execute PHP files. But I have tried to search on the documentation and the internet but I have not found a way to solve the problem I have. My question is, how can I send files or "cookies" in a FastCGI request? What type of record should I use? In what format do I send them?

More detailed explanation.

---

Since I want to execute PHP files, what I want is to send a file to be available in the `$_FILES` variable, but I have not found any way to send them, or information, how should I send them, and what type of "record" should I use? Should I use something like [FCGI_STDIN](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119141816/http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/6?q=node%2F22#S5.3)?

I said that I wanted to send cookies to use sessions in PHP. It seems to me that they work through cookies (that is, sessions use cookies), and I don't know how I can send the session cookie so that PHP receives it. And that way PHP knows that the user already has a session. How can I do it? in which format?

If you want to see my code and the explanation of my code, all of that is [in my answer to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74202534/why-am-i-not-getting-the-fcgi-end-request-record). And now that I've shown you my code. How can I adapt my code to send files or send a cookie? What changes should I make?

Comment: FastCGI is only a protocol for transporting the HTTP request/response between server and web application. The features you want are completely unrelated to FastCGI, bu they are part of the HTTP request/response themselves, Reading/Writing Cookies are part of the HTTP request/response headers, while for the files you need to parse the request body based if the Content-type in the header is multipart/form-data.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes, I understand what you are talking about. But I mean, how do I send them by FastCGI? In what format do I send files or cookies by FastCGI? How should I do it?

Comment: *"how do I send them by FastCGI"* - you don't. It is part of the HTTP message which is included using `contentData` in the FastCGI protocol. It has thus nothing to do with FastCGI itself.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I guess I understand what you mean. But as you can see in my code, I make a manual connection to a service that uses `FastCGI`, I understand that doing that is part of the HTTP message, but what I want to do is how to pass files to it through the socket. Or if I'm definitely wrong on this, how do I pass the file? If it is not for FastCGI I would like to know how I can pass the file

Comment: Consider a HTTP message a container. Both cookie and file are inside the container, i.e. inside the HTTP header and HTTP body which are parts of the HTTP message. FastCGI is the boat which transports the container. It does not change anything inside the container. It does not matter if you use a boat or a truck to transport the container. If you want to get/set cookie and file you need to reach inside the container (HTTP message), not in what transports the container (FastCGI). And to do this you need to understand how HTTP works - which is too broad to describe here.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I understand.  But then.  With the link I added where my code is, how can I adapt my code to send files?  Whether FastCGI is not used, but how do I do it?  Or send cookies

Comment: You set a cookie in the response by using the [Set-Cookie header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie). You send a file by putting it in the response body and setting the right Content-Type header and maybe also setting Content-Disposition if you want to set a filename too. But again, all of this needs a basic understanding of how HTTP works and explaining all of this is too broad.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich It is that I really understand how HTTP works, that is clear to me, what I wanted was to see in code how to send a file, or send a cookie, but in code