# Why am I not getting the FCGI_END_REQUEST record?

Tags: php, rust, fastcgi

I am currently having a problem terminating a [FastCGI](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119141816/http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/6?q=node%2F22#S1) request. Currently this is the code I have:

```
use std::os::unix::net::{UnixStream};
use std::io::{Read, Write};
use std::str;

fn main() {
    const FCGI_VERSION_1: u8    = 1;

    const FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST:u8 = 1;
    const FCGI_END_REQUEST: u8  = 3;
    const FCGI_STDIN: u8        = 5;
    const FCGI_STDOUT: u8       = 6;
    const FCGI_STDERR: u8       = 7;

    const FCGI_RESPONDER: u16  = 1;

    const FCGI_PARAMS: u8 = 4;

    let socket_path = "/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock";

    let mut socket = match UnixStream::connect(socket_path) {
        Ok(sock) => sock,
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Couldn't connect: {e:?}");
            return
        }
    };

    let requestId: u16 = 1;

    let role: u16 = FCGI_RESPONDER;

    let beginRequest = vec![
       // FCGI_Header
       FCGI_VERSION_1, FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST,
       (requestId >> 8) as u8, (requestId & 0xFF) as u8,
       0x00, 0x08, // This is the size of `FCGI_BeginRequestBody`
       0, 0,
       // FCGI_BeginRequestBody
       (role >> 8) as u8, (role & 0xFF) as u8,
       0, // Flags
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, // Reserved
    ];

    socket.write_all(&beginRequest).unwrap();

    // write the FCGI_PARAMS

    let param1_name = "SCRIPT_FILENAME".as_bytes();
    let param1_value = "/var/www/public/index.php".as_bytes();
    let lengths1 = [ param1_name.len() as u8, param1_value.len() as u8 ];
    let params1_len: u16 = (param1_name.len() + param1_value.len() + lengths1.len()) as u16;

    let param2_name = b"REQUEST_METHOD";
    let param2_value = b"GET";
    let lengths2 = [ param2_name.len() as u8, param2_value.len() as u8 ];
    let params2_len: u16 = (param2_name.len() + param2_value.len() + lengths2.len()) as u16;

    let params_len = params1_len + params2_len;
    let paramsRequest = vec![
       FCGI_VERSION_1, FCGI_PARAMS,
       (requestId >> 8) as u8, (requestId & 0xFF) as u8,
       (params_len >> 8) as u8, (params_len & 0xFF) as u8,
       0, 0,
    ];
    socket.write_all (&paramsRequest).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (&lengths1).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param1_name).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param1_value).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (&lengths2).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param2_name).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param2_value).unwrap();

    // get the response
    let requestHeader = vec![
       FCGI_VERSION_1, FCGI_STDIN,
       (requestId >> 8) as u8, (requestId & 0xFF) as u8,
       0, 0,
       0, 0,
    ];

    socket.write_all(&requestHeader).unwrap();

    // read the response
    let mut responseHeader = [0u8; 8];
    socket.read_exact (&mut responseHeader).unwrap();


    // read the padding
    let mut pad = vec![0; responseHeader[7] as usize];

    socket.read_exact (&mut pad).unwrap();

    // read the body
    let responseLength = ((responseHeader[4] as usize) << 8) | (responseHeader[5] as usize);

    let mut responseBody = Vec::new();

    responseBody.resize (responseLength, 0);

    socket.read_exact (&mut responseBody).unwrap();

    println!("Output: {:?}", std::str::from_utf8(&responseBody));
}
```

What my code does (in short) is make a FastCGI request to a `.php` file using the `php-fpm` service. And that code works (up to a point...) well, actually I have the expected output which is this:

> Ok("X-Powered-By: PHP/8.1.11\r\nContent-type: text/html;
> charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\nFirst file")

By the way, my php file only has the following content:

```
<?php

echo "First file";

?>
```

So far, so good. But now what I want to do is receive the record [FCGI_END_REQUEST](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119141816/http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/6?q=node%2F22#S5.5). And for that, according to answers to previous questions (questions made by me, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73965913/how-to-read-all-output-from-a-fastcgi-request)) what I have to do is make a loop and read all the content of `FCGI_STDIN` until I receive the record `FCGI_END_REQUEST`. What according to me (if I'm wrong please tell me) would be to do this:

```
let mut output: String = String::new();

loop {
    // get the response
    let requestHeader = vec![
    FCGI_VERSION_1, FCGI_STDOUT,
    (requestId >> 8) as u8, (requestId & 0xFF) as u8,
    0, 0,
    0, 0,
    ];

    socket.write_all(&requestHeader).unwrap();

    // read the response
    let mut responseHeader = [0u8; 8];
    socket.read_exact (&mut responseHeader).unwrap();

    if responseHeader[1] != FCGI_STDOUT && responseHeader[1] != FCGI_STDERR{
        if responseHeader[1] == FCGI_END_REQUEST {
            println!("FCGI_END_REQUEST");
            break;
        } else {
            println!("NOT FCGI_END_REQUEST");
            break;
        }
    }

    // read the padding
    let mut pad = vec![0; responseHeader[7] as usize];

    socket.read_exact (&mut pad).unwrap();

    // read the body
    let responseLength = ((responseHeader[4] as usize) << 8) | (responseHeader[5] as usize);

    let mut responseBody = Vec::new();

    responseBody.resize (responseLength, 0);

    let format = format!("{}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&responseBody));

    output.push_str(format.as_str());
}


println!("Output: {:?}", output);
```

This code is replacing all the first code I showed from the "get the response" comment to the end of the file. What I do is loop reading `FCGI_STDIN` and when it comes across a record other than `FCGI_STDOUT` or `FCGI_STDERR` it prints if `FCGI_END_REQUEST` was the type of record that was found. So now this is my full code:

```
use std::os::unix::net::{UnixStream};
use std::io::{Read, Write};
use std::str;

fn main() {
    const FCGI_VERSION_1: u8    = 1;

    const FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST:u8 = 1;
    const FCGI_END_REQUEST: u8  = 3;
    const FCGI_STDIN: u8        = 5;
    const FCGI_STDOUT: u8       = 6;
    const FCGI_STDERR: u8       = 7;

    const FCGI_RESPONDER: u16  = 1;

    const FCGI_PARAMS: u8 = 4;

    let socket_path = "/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock";

    let mut socket = match UnixStream::connect(socket_path) {
        Ok(sock) => sock,
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Couldn't connect: {e:?}");
            return
        }
    };

    let requestId: u16 = 1;

    let role: u16 = FCGI_RESPONDER;

    let beginRequest = vec![
       // FCGI_Header
       FCGI_VERSION_1, FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST,
       (requestId >> 8) as u8, (requestId & 0xFF) as u8,
       0x00, 0x08, // This is the size of `FCGI_BeginRequestBody`
       0, 0,
       // FCGI_BeginRequestBody
       (role >> 8) as u8, (role & 0xFF) as u8,
       0, // Flags
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, // Reserved
    ];

    socket.write_all(&beginRequest).unwrap();

    // write the FCGI_PARAMS

    let param1_name = "SCRIPT_FILENAME".as_bytes();
    let param1_value = "/var/www/public/index.php".as_bytes();
    let lengths1 = [ param1_name.len() as u8, param1_value.len() as u8 ];
    let params1_len: u16 = (param1_name.len() + param1_value.len() + lengths1.len()) as u16;

    let param2_name = b"REQUEST_METHOD";
    let param2_value = b"GET";
    let lengths2 = [ param2_name.len() as u8, param2_value.len() as u8 ];
    let params2_len: u16 = (param2_name.len() + param2_value.len() + lengths2.len()) as u16;

    let params_len = params1_len + params2_len;
    let paramsRequest = vec![
       FCGI_VERSION_1, FCGI_PARAMS,
       (requestId >> 8) as u8, (requestId & 0xFF) as u8,
       (params_len >> 8) as u8, (params_len & 0xFF) as u8,
       0, 0,
    ];

    socket.write_all (&paramsRequest).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (&lengths1).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param1_name).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param1_value).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (&lengths2).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param2_name).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param2_value).unwrap();

    let mut output: String = String::new();

    loop {
        // get the response
        let requestHeader = vec![
        FCGI_VERSION_1, FCGI_STDOUT,
        (requestId >> 8) as u8, (requestId & 0xFF) as u8,
        0, 0,
        0, 0,
        ];
    
        socket.write_all(&requestHeader).unwrap();
    
        // read the response
        let mut responseHeader = [0u8; 8];
        socket.read_exact (&mut responseHeader).unwrap();
    
        if responseHeader[1] != FCGI_STDOUT && responseHeader[1] != FCGI_STDERR{
            if responseHeader[1] == FCGI_END_REQUEST {
                println!("FCGI_END_REQUEST");
                break;
            } else {
                println!("NOT FCGI_END_REQUEST: {}", responseHeader[1]);
                break;
            }
        }
    
        // read the padding
        let mut pad = vec![0; responseHeader[7] as usize];
    
        socket.read_exact (&mut pad).unwrap();
    
        // read the body
        let responseLength = ((responseHeader[4] as usize) << 8) | (responseHeader[5] as usize);
    
        let mut responseBody = Vec::new();
    
        responseBody.resize (responseLength, 0);
    
        let format = format!("{}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&responseBody));
    
        output.push_str(format.as_str());
    }
    
    
    println!("Output: {:?}", output);
}
```

The problem is that the output of this program is this:

> NOT FCGI_END_REQUEST Output:
> "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0

So what am I doing wrong? What's wrong with my code?

---

I did what I was told in the comments, which is to print the value of `responseHeader[1]`. So change `println!("NOT FCGI_END_REQUEST");` to `println!("NOT FCGI_END_REQUEST: {}", responseHeader[1]);`. And I get this output:

> NOT FCGI_END_REQUEST: 45 Output:
> "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"

---

Based on what I have understood from what has been said in the chat. I'm going to add a `println!("{:?}", foo);` after each  `socket.read_exact (&mut responseHeader)`. So my loop would look like this:

```
loop {
    // get the response
    let requestHeader = vec![
    FCGI_VERSION_1, FCGI_STDOUT,
    (requestId >> 8) as u8, (requestId & 0xFF) as u8,
    0, 0,
    0, 0,
    ];

    socket.write_all(&requestHeader).unwrap();

    // read the response
    let mut responseHeader = [0u8; 8];
    socket.read_exact (&mut responseHeader).unwrap();

    // "debug"
    println!("{:?}", responseHeader);

    if responseHeader[1] != FCGI_STDOUT && responseHeader[1] != FCGI_STDERR{
        if responseHeader[1] == FCGI_END_REQUEST {
            println!("FCGI_END_REQUEST");
            break;
        } else {
            println!("NOT FCGI_END_REQUEST: {}", responseHeader[1]);
            break;
        }
    }

    // read the padding
    let mut pad = vec![0; responseHeader[6] as usize];

    socket.read_exact (&mut pad).unwrap();

    // "debug";
    println!("{:?}", pad);

    // read the body
    let responseLength = ((responseHeader[4] as usize) << 8) | (responseHeader[5] as usize);

    let mut responseBody = Vec::new();

    responseBody.resize (responseLength, 0);

    let format = format!("{}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&responseBody));

    output.push_str(format.as_str());
}
```

With that code. I get this output:

```
[1, 6, 0, 1, 0, 78, 2, 0]
[88, 45]
[80, 111, 119, 101, 114, 101, 100, 45]
NOT FCGI_END_REQUEST: 111
Output: "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
```

Now, also from what has been said in the chat I understand that there are some other problems with my code, but I have not understood exactly what they mean and how to correct them.

Comment: You can't read `FCGI_STDIN`, you can only write to it (which is what you do here) but you don't need to. In order to understand what's happening, you need to print the type of the message you receive from the FCGI server (i.e. `responseHeader[1]`) since it's obviously none of those you expected…

Comment: @Jmb What do you mean by "You can't read FCGI_STDIN, you can only write to it'", do you mean that the output should be read from another record type?

Comment: `FCGI_STDIN` is a message _you_ send when you have data to write. The output should be read from the `FCGI_STDOUT` (or `FCGI_STDERR`) messages that you receive.

Comment: @Jmb But even though I read from `FCGI STDOUT` I get exactly the same result.

Comment: The point is you _don't_ read from `FCGI_STDOUT`, the server is sending some other message which is neither `FCGI_STDOUT`, `FCGI_STDERR` nor `FCGI_END_REQUEST` and you error out. You need to at least print the message type that you receive so that we can know what the server is trying to tell you.

Comment: Plus, you shouldn't write to `FCGI_STDIN` in the loop where you're reading from `FCGI_STDOUT` (the server may actually be complaining that it receives unexpected `FCGI_STDIN` messages, but again the only way to know for sure is if you print the type of the messages you receive).

Comment: 116 is not a valid message type, so what you're reading is not a response header, you've read too much or too little before and got out of sync. Can you post the full exact code you're using?

Comment: @Jmb With the exact code that is there (including the loop) I get 72. It's the same code, exactly the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249088/discussion-between-jmb-and-new1).

Comment: Are you aware of [this](https://crates.io/crates/fastcgi-client)?

Comment: @Olivier I have seen the crate. But I want to make my own since the existing libraries do not have the way to do what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already found a way to get `FCGI_END_REQUEST` (or so I think). I did it with part of [Jmb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5397009/jmb)'s answer and with something he said in the chat. The first thing I did was write `FCGI_STDOUT` just once and before doing the `loop`. Then I create the `responseHeader` variable and read the data. And then, thanks to Jmb's answer, I read the padding after reading the response body and read `responseHeader[6]` and not `responseHeader[7]` (as I did before). So my code looks like this:

```
use std::os::unix::net::{UnixStream};
use std::io::{Read, Write};
use std::str;

fn main() {
    const FCGI_VERSION_1: u8    = 1;

    const FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST:u8 = 1;
    const FCGI_END_REQUEST: u8  = 3;
    const FCGI_STDIN: u8        = 5;
    const FCGI_STDOUT: u8       = 6;
    const FCGI_STDERR: u8       = 7;

    const FCGI_RESPONDER: u16  = 1;

    const FCGI_PARAMS: u8 = 4;

    let socket_path = "/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock";

    let mut socket = match UnixStream::connect(socket_path) {
        Ok(sock) => sock,
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Couldn't connect: {e:?}");
            return
        }
    };

    let requestId: u16 = 1;

    let role: u16 = FCGI_RESPONDER;

    let beginRequest = vec![
       // FCGI_Header
       FCGI_VERSION_1, FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST,
       (requestId >> 8) as u8, (requestId & 0xFF) as u8,
       0x00, 0x08, // This is the size of `FCGI_BeginRequestBody`
       0, 0,
       // FCGI_BeginRequestBody
       (role >> 8) as u8, (role & 0xFF) as u8,
       0, // Flags
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, // Reserved
    ];

    socket.write_all(&beginRequest).unwrap();

    // write the FCGI_PARAMS

    let param1_name = "SCRIPT_FILENAME".as_bytes();
    let param1_value = "/home/davebook-arch/projects/so/index.php".as_bytes();
    let lengths1 = [ param1_name.len() as u8, param1_value.len() as u8 ];
    let params1_len: u16 = (param1_name.len() + param1_value.len() + lengths1.len()) as u16;

    let param2_name = b"REQUEST_METHOD";
    let param2_value = b"GET";
    let lengths2 = [ param2_name.len() as u8, param2_value.len() as u8 ];
    let params2_len: u16 = (param2_name.len() + param2_value.len() + lengths2.len()) as u16;

    let params_len = params1_len + params2_len;
    let paramsRequest = vec![
       FCGI_VERSION_1, FCGI_PARAMS,
       (requestId >> 8) as u8, (requestId & 0xFF) as u8,
       (params_len >> 8) as u8, (params_len & 0xFF) as u8,
       0, 0,
    ];

    socket.write_all (&paramsRequest).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (&lengths1).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param1_name).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param1_value).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (&lengths2).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param2_name).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param2_value).unwrap();

    let mut stdout: String = String::new();

    // get the response
    let requestHeader = vec![
        FCGI_VERSION_1, FCGI_STDOUT,
        (requestId >> 8) as u8, (requestId & 0xFF) as u8,
        0, 0,
        0, 0,
    ];

    socket.write_all(&requestHeader).unwrap();

    loop {
        // read the response header
        let mut responseHeader = [0u8; 8];
        socket.read_exact (&mut responseHeader).unwrap();
    
        if responseHeader[1] != FCGI_STDOUT && responseHeader[1] != FCGI_STDERR{

            if responseHeader[1] == FCGI_END_REQUEST {
                println!("FCGI_END_REQUEST: {:?}", responseHeader);
                break;
            } else {
                println!("NOT FCGI_END_REQUEST: {}", responseHeader[1]);
                break;
            }
        }

        // read the body
        let responseLength = ((responseHeader[4] as usize) << 8) | (responseHeader[5] as usize);

        let mut responseBody = vec![0; responseLength];

        socket.read_exact (&mut responseBody).unwrap();

        stdout.push_str(&String::from_utf8_lossy(&responseBody));

        // read the padding
        let mut pad = vec![0; responseHeader[6] as usize];

        socket.read_exact (&mut pad).unwrap();
    }
    
    println!("Output: {:?}", stdout);
}
```

And with that code, I get this output:

```
FCGI_END_REQUEST: [1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 8, 0, 0]
Output: "X-Powered-By: PHP/8.1.11\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\nFirst file"
```

With that I really think I am getting the `FCGI_END_REQUEST` record (I highly doubt that I am confusing the output and that it is not really the `FCGI_END_REQUEST` record)

### About the bounty

I'm really willing to give  bounty to someone who gives an answer on things like:

- Things I do wrong (or things that can be improved)
- Why do I get `FCGI_END_REQUEST` both reading from `FCGI_STDIN` and `FCGI_STDOUT`? According to Jmb I shouldn't read from `FCGI_STDIN` but if I do I get the same result

Or basically, I'm willing to give a reward for a more detailed answer. If when the reward ends there is no more detailed answer I will accept my answer as correct.

Comment: I didn't say you shouldn't read from `FCGI_STDIN`, I said you _can't_ read from it. That's just plain impossible. What you're doing when you send an `FCGI_STDIN` request is _writing_ to `FCGI_STDIN`, not reading from it. By the same token, you should never _send_ an `FCGI_STDOUT` message, and `php-fpm` (or whatever) would be allowed to consider it an error and summarily close the connection when you do.

Comment: @Jmb But then why if I read from FCGI_STDIN do I get the same output?

Comment: You don't read from `FCGI_STDIN`, it's just impossible, you can't do it. What you call "reading from `FCGI_STDIN`" is that you _**write**_ to `FCGI_STDIN`, then read from `FCGI_STDOUT` anyway. Why would writing to stdin before (or after) reading from stdout be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code:

- You're writing several `FCGI_STDOUT` messages in your reading loop. According to table A in the spec, you should never write such a message: `FCGI_STDOUT` messages should only go *from the "App"* (i.e. php-fpm or whatever FCGI application you're talking to) *to the WS* (i.e. your program).
- This stems from a misconception about how and when `FCGI_STDOUT` messages are sent: you don't need to do anything to request the output, instead the "App" will send `FCGI_STDOUT` messages spontaneously whenever they have something to say.
- You're reading the padding and content in the wrong order (see the definition of `FCGI_Record`: the content comes before the padding). In fact you're not reading the content at all (you're missing a call to `socket.read_exact (&mut responseBody)`).

According to your traces, `php-fpm` is sending you a single `FCGI_STDOUT` message that contains 78 bytes of data followed by 2 bytes of padding. The data starts with `88, 45, 80, 111, 119, 101, 114, 101, 100, 45` which translates to "X-Powered-". But you skip the first two bytes as if they were padding, you never read the message body, and then you read the next 8 bytes as if they were a new message header. When you attempt to extract a type from these 8 bytes, you get an invalid value and your program errors out.

Fixed code (untested):

```
use std::os::unix::net::{UnixStream};
use std::io::{Read, Write};
use std::str;

fn main() {
    const FCGI_VERSION_1: u8    = 1;

    const FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST:u8 = 1;
    const FCGI_END_REQUEST: u8  = 3;
    const FCGI_STDIN: u8        = 5;
    const FCGI_STDOUT: u8       = 6;
    const FCGI_STDERR: u8       = 7;

    const FCGI_RESPONDER: u16  = 1;

    const FCGI_PARAMS: u8 = 4;

    let socket_path = "/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock";

    let mut socket = match UnixStream::connect(socket_path) {
        Ok(sock) => sock,
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Couldn't connect: {e:?}");
            return
        }
    };

    let requestId: u16 = 1;

    let role: u16 = FCGI_RESPONDER;

    let beginRequest = vec![
       // FCGI_Header
       FCGI_VERSION_1, FCGI_BEGIN_REQUEST,
       (requestId >> 8) as u8, (requestId & 0xFF) as u8,
       0x00, 0x08, // This is the size of `FCGI_BeginRequestBody`
       0, 0,
       // FCGI_BeginRequestBody
       (role >> 8) as u8, (role & 0xFF) as u8,
       0, // Flags
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, // Reserved
    ];

    socket.write_all(&beginRequest).unwrap();

    // write the FCGI_PARAMS

    let param1_name = "SCRIPT_FILENAME".as_bytes();
    let param1_value = "/var/www/public/index.php".as_bytes();
    let lengths1 = [ param1_name.len() as u8, param1_value.len() as u8 ];
    let params1_len: u16 = (param1_name.len() + param1_value.len() + lengths1.len()) as u16;

    let param2_name = b"REQUEST_METHOD";
    let param2_value = b"GET";
    let lengths2 = [ param2_name.len() as u8, param2_value.len() as u8 ];
    let params2_len: u16 = (param2_name.len() + param2_value.len() + lengths2.len()) as u16;

    let params_len = params1_len + params2_len;
    let paramsRequest = vec![
       FCGI_VERSION_1, FCGI_PARAMS,
       (requestId >> 8) as u8, (requestId & 0xFF) as u8,
       (params_len >> 8) as u8, (params_len & 0xFF) as u8,
       0, 0,
    ];

    socket.write_all (&paramsRequest).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (&lengths1).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param1_name).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param1_value).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (&lengths2).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param2_name).unwrap();
    socket.write_all (param2_value).unwrap();

    let mut output: String = String::new();

    // get the response
    loop {
        // read the response header
        let mut responseHeader = [0u8; 8];
        socket.read_exact (&mut responseHeader).unwrap();
    
        if responseHeader[1] != FCGI_STDOUT && responseHeader[1] != FCGI_STDERR{
            if responseHeader[1] == FCGI_END_REQUEST {
                println!("FCGI_END_REQUEST");
                break;
            } else {
                println!("NOT FCGI_END_REQUEST: {}", responseHeader[1]);
                break;
            }
        }
    
        // read the body
        let responseLength = ((responseHeader[4] as usize) << 8) | (responseHeader[5] as usize);
        let mut responseBody = vec![0; responseLength];
        socket.read_exact (&mut responseBody).unwrap();
        output.push_str(&String::from_utf8_lossy(&responseBody));

        // read the padding
        let mut pad = vec![0; responseHeader[7] as usize];
        socket.read_exact (&mut pad).unwrap();
    }
    
    println!("Output: {:?}", output);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your code, and although some things became clearer to me, when I run the program the console stays black without any results and the program never ends.